# MySQL Replication wont start

Tags: mysql

When starting my replication I get the error message `Last_IO_Errno: 2003`.
After trying everything I found in several forums it should have to do something with access rights, but I don't know what. So far I tried:

- turn off the firewall
- GRANT for user "replication"
- STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;
- Set MASTER_LOG_POS and MASTER_LOG_FILE again manually

I still can't get a connection established. The DB is there and also the user works (tested via `mysql --host=IP_ADDR --port=33060 -u replication -p`)

What else could be the problem? What else can I do to start replication?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Last_IO_Errno%3A+2003&oq=Last_IO_Errno%3A+2003&aqs=chrome..69i57.921j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Rick, that was the first I have done and I checked it double/tripple times that all access properties look fine. Only MySQL repl. can't get access...